# Python list reference in a function.

Tags: python

I'm having trouble understanding the odd behaviour in python functions if i pass in a list. 
I made the following functions:

```
def func(x):
    y = [4, 5, 6]
    x = y

def funcsecond(x):
    y = [4, 5, 6]
    x[1] = y[1]

x = [1, 2, 3]
```

When i call func(x) and then print out x , it prints out [1, 2, 3], just the way x was before,  it doesnt assign the list y to x. However, if i call funcsecond(x), it assigns 5 to the second position of x. Why is that so? When i assign the whole list, it doesn't do anything, but when i assign only one element, it changes the list i originally called it with.
Thank you very much and i hope you understand what im intending to say , i'm having a hard time expressing myself in English.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is happening beacuse x points to a object which is mutable.

```
def func(x): # here x is a local variable which refers to the object[1,2,3]
    y = [4, 5, 6]
    x = y  #now the local variable x refers to the object [4,5,6]

def funcsecond(x): # here x is a local variable which refers to the object[1,2,3]
    y = [4, 5, 6]
    x[1] = y[1]  # it means [1,2,3][1]=5 , means you changed the object x was pointing to

x = [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: How come X suddenly becomes local variable.It should still be the reference even after assigning rit?

Comment: `x` is a local variable inside the functions because it is used in the arguments (inside the function header).

Comment: It is a reference. Bit in `func` this reference is reassigned to point to a new object.

Comment: Thank you , i understand it a little bit better now. So , if I want the first function to change x to y , i just have to do x[:] = y , right ?

Comment: @geekid you just need to do a shallw copy using slice assign like this x=y[:]

Comment: @InternalServerError No, that will be an assignment again. geekkid, I think you are right, that's what Ignacio's link above suggests.

Answer (score 9):

The former **rebinds** the **name**, the latter **mutates** the **object**. Changes to the name only exist in local scope, whereas a mutated object remains mutated after the scope is exited.

Comment: Might need a little more explanation than this - then again, this is no doubt a dupe.

Comment: how does python determine when to rebind and when to mutate?

Comment: It rebinds when you assign to a bare name (e.g. `foo =`). Every other assignment operation is (usually) mutation.

Comment: Yeah! got it. But how can i  replace all values of x with y.should i manually loop through each element?

Comment: @ignacio: great!...but one more silly question.slice assign just shallow copies..so how will i deep copy?

Comment: You need to perform the deep copy yourself before slice-assigning.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12850/discussion-between-internal-server-error-and-ignacio-vazquez-abrams)