# Short Python code not showing what I expected

Tags: python

Hello there fellow developers,

The following is a question from a Python's studying list.
The question asks to choose between 5 answers about which would be the output of `print(v, m, n)`.

a) [1, 2, 3], [2, 4, 6], [3, 6, 9]

b) [3, 6, 9], [3, 6, 9], [3, 6, 9]

c) [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [3, 6, 9]

d) [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [2, 4, 6]

e) [3, 6, 9], [1, 2, 3], [3, 6, 9]

From my beginner perspective, `v = [1, 2, 3]` and `m` after running `f1(v)` should be `m = [1, 2, 3]` as well (and on debug I see `m` as `[1, 2, 3]` before hitting the `n = f2(v)` line). Then `n` should be `[3, 6, 9]` after running `f2(v)`(because of `m[i] *= 3`).
I know the right answer is B, I just cannot figure out why.
Although wrong, my thinking process point to `[1, 2, 3][1, 2, 3][3, 6, 9]` as the answer.

```py
def f1(v):
    for elem in v:
        elem *= 2
    return v

def f2(m):
    for i in range(len(m)):
        m[i] *= 3
    return m

v = [1,2,3]
m = f1(v)
n = f2(v)

print(v, m, n)
```

Please help me figure out why the output of this Python code is

```py
[3, 6, 9]
[3, 6, 9]
[3, 6, 9]
```

instead of

```py
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
[3, 6, 9]
```

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python list reference in a function.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11136746/python-list-reference-in-a-function)

Comment: v, m, and n are all names for v. f2 changes the values of v then after that you print v, m and n but remember those are all names for v.

Answer (score 1):

The problem arises from how lists work in python - in the second function you are actually altering m and not just returning a copy. The way you would overcome this is by creating a copy of the list before performing alterations on it.

Comment: I edited the question so you guys understand that it's a practice question and not something I'm trying to build

Answer (score 1):

To understand this behaviour, you first have to know a couple of things -

1. In python data is represented through **objects** (not same as variables).
2. A variable is nothing but a **reference to an object**.
3. Every object in python has a **unique identity**. The built-in function `id()` returns the identity of the object.

    Example -

   ```
   def print_value_and_id(obj, name):
       print(f"{name} =", obj)
       print(f"id({name}) =", id(obj))


   a = 0
   b = 0

   print_value_and_id(a, 'a')
   print_value_and_id(b, 'b')
   ```

   Run the above [code](https://godbolt.org/z/canzobfYv) and you'll see id of both `a` and `b` is the same. This is because both `a` and `b` holds the reference to a single object (change value of `b` to 1 and the id of `b` will be different).
4. Some objects in python are **immutable**, i.e., once created the value of the object can not be modified (but it can be destroyed). Any object that is not immutable, is **mutable**.

    
    Immutable objects are of *built-in datatypes* like `int`, `bool`, `float`, `complex`, `str`, `tuple`, `bytes`, `frozenset`.

    Mutable objects are of built-in datatypes like `list`, `dict`, `set`, `bytearray`, any user-defined class.

    Example -

   ```
   a = 0
   print_value_and_id(a, 'a')
   a = 1
   print_value_and_id(a, 'a')
   ```

   Run the above [code](https://godbolt.org/z/q6bKbMzs3) and see the id of `a` changes. This is because the value of the `int` object (that `a` was referencing) could not be changed (immutable). So `a` is given the reference to a new `int` object with value 1.

    Now let's see the example of a mutable object like `list` -

   ```
   a = [0]
   print_value_and_id(a, 'a')
   a[0] = 1
   print_value_and_id(a, 'a')
   ```

   Run the above [code](https://godbolt.org/z/3oadqhsc1) and you can see that the id of `a` does not change.
5. Functions in python pass arguments by reference, i.e., the same object is passed.

Now let's come to your code. First we'll analyze function `f1` -

Driver code -

```
global_list = [1,2,3]
print_value_and_id(global_list, "global_list")
print("")

m = f1(global_list)
print_value_and_id(m, "m") # same id as global_list
print("")
```

Definition of `f1` -

```
def f1(f1_list):
    print("f1 called")
    i = 0
    
    # arguments are passed by reference
    # so f1_list and global_list has same id
    print_value_and_id(f1_list, "f1_list")
    print("")

    for elem in f1_list:
        # elem holds reference to an object of type 'int' (immutable)
        # which is contained in a 'list' (mutable)

        print(f"iteration no - {i}")
        
        # elem and f1_list[i] holds reference to the same object
        print_value_and_id(elem, f"elem")
        print_value_and_id(f1_list[i], f"f1_list[{i}]")
        
        elem *= 2
        
        # id of elem changes, since elem is immutable
        print_value_and_id(elem, f"elem")
        # id of f1_list[i] stays unchanged, since f1_list[i] is not modified
        print_value_and_id(f1_list[i], f"f1_list[{i}]")
        # now, elem and f1_list[i] holds reference to the different objects
        
        i += 1
        print("")
    
    # f1_list is not changed in the above loop
    # so, global_list is also not changed
    print_value_and_id(f1_list, "f1_list")
    print("")
    
    return f1_list
```

Run the above [code](https://godbolt.org/z/9b4bhah83) and observe the output step by step along with the comments.

 Now let's analyze function `f2` -

Driver code -

```
global_list = [1,2,3]
print_value_and_id(global_list, "global_list")
print("")

n = f2(global_list)
print_value_and_id(n, "n") # same id as global_list
print("")
```

Definition of `f2` -

```
def f2(f2_list):
    print("f2 called")

    # arguments are passed by reference
    # so f2_list and global_list has same id
    print_value_and_id(f2_list, "f2_list")
    print("")
    
    for i in range(len(f2_list)):
        print(f"iteration no - {i}")

        print_value_and_id(f2_list[i], f"f2_list[{i}]")
        
        f2_list[i] *= 3
        
        # id of f2_list[i] changes
        print_value_and_id(f2_list[i], f"f2_list[{i}]")
        print("")
    
    # here f2_list is actually changed, so v is also changed
    # but id of f2_list is still same as v, since 'list' is mutable
    print_value_and_id(f2_list, "f2_list")
    print("")

    return f2_list
```

Run the above [code](https://godbolt.org/z/5xjss3Ga9) and observe the output along with the comments.

In both of the above cases, the id of `m` and `n` is same as the id of `global_list`. This means all of them points to the same 'list' object. If they would have been pointing to different objects then the output of `print(global_list, m, n)` would have been `[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [3, 6, 9]`, but since they all point to the same object, the last updated value of the object is displayed, i.e., `[3, 6, 9], [3, 6, 9], [3, 6, 9]`

Refs : https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html

Answer (score 0):

Lists are "mutable". That means if you change the list, it doesn't copy the list somewhere else and gives you a changed copy, but it just changes the list.

In function one (`f1`) you return `v` without changing it, because you're not saving anything. What you want to do is collect the elements.

```py
def f1(v):
    results = []
    for elem in v:
        elem *= 2
        results.append(elem)
    return results
```

In function two (`f2`) you're changing the list you put in. This causes so-called side effects, which is usually nasty and should be avoided.
You should (again) collect the results in a different list.

```py
def f2(m):
    results = []
    for i in range(len(m)):
        results.append(m[i] * 3)
    return results
```

Also take a look [here](https://realpython.com/python-pass-by-reference/).

Comment: I edited the question so you guys understand that it's a practice question and not something I'm trying to build.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, lists are passed by reference. So when you index the list as `m[i]` it actually refers to the original list that was passed. Hence, when you assign new value to each element of the list (`m[i] *= 3`), it updates the original list. And also note that, all three variables `v`, `m`, `n` refers to the the same list in your code. Therefore you got `[3, 6, 9] [3, 6, 9] [3, 6, 9]` as output.

What you really wanna do is make a copy of the list,

```py
def f1(v):
    for elem in v:
        elem *= 2
    return v

def f2(m):
    # use copy method to copy
    # m_copy = m.copy()
    
    # or you can use slicing
    m_copy = m[:]

    for i in range(len(m_copy)):
        m_copy[i] *= 3
    return m_copy

v = [1,2,3]
m = f1(v)
n = f2(v)

print(v, m, n)
```

You can also use list comprehension to make the function smaller,

```py
def f2(m):
    return [i * 3 for i in m]
```

If you want to explore more about list comprehensions, check out the official documentation here https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions.

Comment: I edited the question so you guys understand that it's a practice question and not something I'm trying to build.

Answer (score 0):

Python's operators turn into method calls under the covers. `elem *= 2` becomes

```
elem = elem.__imul__(2)
```

`elem` gets to choose what augmented multiplication means to it. Notice that python asks for multiplication, but then assigns whatever is returned to the original variable. Immutable types such as `int` will usually create a new object for the assignment. Mutable types will update their own internal state and return their own `self`. Usually. A mutable type could return a new copy of itself or maybe a completely different object is returned. Some clever programmer could write a class that does something completely off the wall and use your code for very different purposes than you intended.

Since you didn't assign `m` to anything, the result of the multiplication is lost.

Python's indexing operations also become method calls. `m_copy[i] *= 3` becomes (I'm using a temporary variable for clarification but there is no intermediate assignment in code)

```
_m = m_copy.__getitem__(i)
m_copy.__setitem__(i, _m.__imul__(3))
```

`_m` is what you called `m` in the first example and the same rules apply for the multiplication. The difference here is that python sets that return value back into the original list. Unlike the first example, the new value takes the place of the old value in the list.

**As for the updated question**

```
v = [1,2,3]      # create a list
m = f1(v)        # f1 returns its parameter unchanged, so m = v
                 #    that is, 2 references to that single list
n = f2(v)        # f2 updates its parameter in-place and returns it
                 #     so v = m = n, which is the original list
                 #     that has been modified

print(v, m, n)   # print that single list 3 times
```

Comment: I edited the question so you guys understand that it's a practice question and not something I'm trying to build.

Comment: @fcoser - updated to show how that list is printed 3 times.